# How to configure OAuth with Goodreads

Tags: javascript, api, oauth

I am building an app using HTML, CSS, and Javascript, and am trying to configure OAuth to use it to access data from the Goodreads API. I basically want to get a list of books that a Goodreads member has read in the current year and display statistics about the metadata of these books. I'm pretty new to Javascript and using API's and don't have a super good grasp on OAuth and API authentication in general so I would really appreciate it if it could be explained as simply as possible.

From what I understand I need to create a login button on my page that contains a link that looks something like this:

```
http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=SCDMymQWcIE8GnxmSA
```

When the user clicks this button they'll visit `goodreads.com` where they'll login to their account. After accepting the permissions, the user will be redirected to back to your site along with an access token that would contain the [user's ID](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#auth.user). At this point I would use the user ID to pull data about the books on their shelves.

I'm not really sure how to go about writing this in my Javascript file though. How do I go about authorizing via OAuth and storing the user's ID? From the [Goodreads Developers group](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/18339231-oauth2) it seems like the Goodreads API uses OAuth 1.0 which I believe is relevant to how I will need to approach this.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @iOS_Binod Unfortunately no :( Have you since?

Comment: Yes i did that in iOS app.. I am using oAuthswift lib for calling Goodreads api.  This is github URL: https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift